# Find character characters except when surrounded by specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string: `"${styles.button} ${styles[color]} ${styles[size]} ${styles[_state]} ${iconOnly ? styles.iconOnly : ''}"`, and I'm trying to use regex to find all the spaces, except for spaces that are part of an interpolation string (`${...}`).

I'm willing to admit that regex might not be the right tool for this job, but I'm curious what I'm missing.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is replace the spaces with a newline character.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use regex to parse arbitrary JS template strings. That isn't an easy task in the general case and regex is probably the wrong tool for the job--it's likely an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you provide more context (why do you need to parse JS template strings in the first place?) and show an attempt? Thanks.

Comment: This is for a class attribute on an HTML template. Trying to do 2 things.. figure out if there is more that one class listed, and if there are, replace the spaces with newline characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string in interpolation string and non-interpolation string sequences and then only modify the odd sequences (the resulting array always starts with a non-interpolation string, don't worry about that). This has to be done, because regular expressions are limited in the states they can remember (for more about that study CS). A solution would be:

```js
var string = "${styles.button} ${styles[color]} ${styles[size]} ${styles[_state]} ${iconOnly ? styles.iconOnly : ''}";
var result = string
// split in non-interpolation string and interpolation string sequences
.split(/(\${[^}]*})/g)
// modify the sequences with odd indices ( non-interpolation)
.map((part, i) => (i % 2 ? part : part.replace(/ +/g, '')))
// concatenate the strings
.join('');

console.log(result);
```

But also mind the comment by [ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6243352/ggorlen) on your question:

> Looks like you're trying to use regex to parse arbitrary JS template strings. That isn't an easy task in the general case and regex is probably the wrong tool for the job--it's likely an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you provide more context (why do you need to parse JS template strings in the first place?) and show an attempt? Thanks.

Comment: I was able to use regular strings with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only have `${...}` patterns separated by space as per your example you can apply this regex:

```js
var str = "${styles.button} ${styles[color]} ${styles[size]} ${styles[_state]} ${iconOnly ? styles.iconOnly : ''}"
var re = /(\}) +(\$\{)/g;
var result = str.replace(re, "$1\n$2");
console.log('result: ' + result);
```

Result:

```
result: ${styles.button}
${styles[color]}
${styles[size]}
${styles[_state]}
${iconOnly ? styles.iconOnly : ''}
```

Comment: I could potentially have regular string that aren't interpolated too.

Comment: @m0ngr31 This removes the spaces between interpolation strings only if ther is no other character. Do you want another solution? (That also finds spaces at the end and the beginning and if "...} space-> <-space ${..")

Comment: @NiklasE. yeah, if you have one

Comment: @m0ngr31: Indeed, if you have other text between the `${...}` pattern then use @NiklasE.'s solution. In future it would be helpful to get a specific sample string that shows what you actually have as input.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with a simple find ' \$' (without quotes), replace with '\n$' (without quotes) - in sublime text regex search, works well